# focus is not working after the blur event to the textbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

while dragging the div, i need to remove the focus of the input and on dropping it, add focus. I have enclosed my code here.

```
$('.ui-draggable').mousedown(function(){ 
    $(this).find('input').blur();
    $(this).addClass('draggable');
}).mouseup(function(){ 
    $('.draggable').find('input').focus();
    $(this).removeClass('draggable');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to call 'blur', as the input will lose focus when you click the ui-draggable element. You should probably use the [stop-event of draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop).

```
$('.ui-draggable').on( "dragstop", function( event, ui ) {
    $('yourinputselector').focus();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have used dragstart and dragstop option in jqueryui. on dragstart, i removed focus of the textbox and on dragstop, i added focus to the textbox. i need one more clarification is that, why my above code didn't worked. is there any mistake on that?

Comment: No obvoius mistakes really, just figured it would be better to use events for what they are intended for. Although without knowing what your html looks like, I don't know if $(this).find('input') finds the input.